# ScriptAssert script to read from properties?

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am using ScriptAssert and the script work's fine. Now I would like to move the script to properties file.

I am able to read PONumber.mandatory as part of message. I am unable to read **PONumber.mandatory.script** as part of **script**. Any help is appreciated.

ValidationMessages.properties

```
PONumber.mandatory.script=!(_.OBJSTATE.equals('RELEASED') &&  (_.PONumber == '' ))
PONumber.mandatory=PONumber value is Mandatory
```

In Java:

```
@ScriptAssert(lang="javascript",script="{PONumber.mandatory.script}",alias = "_",message="{PONumber.mandatory}")
```

Comment: I think that's not possible as script is evaluated "as is" without checking properties file. So you either would need to move the script from properties file to constraint declaration itself or create a custom validator for ScriptAssert which would read property files.

Comment: Thanks mark. You are right. For now I moved the script to a field and referring it.